# understanding tensorflow basicLSTMCell parameter input

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I having some trouble understanding the tensorflow BasicLSTMCell num_units input parameter.

I have seen other posts but I am not following so hoping a simple example will help.

So say we have the following LTSM RNN model below. How do I determine the number units the cells require? Is it possible to have such a structure for a LTSM RNN?

```
   Input Vec       1st Hidden Layer     2nd Hidden Layer     Output
   20 x 1          20 x 1               5 x 1                3 x 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow, I have given a sample code for your model by using a dynamic rnn (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn)

```
N_INPUT = 20
N_TIME_STEPS = #Define here
N_HIDDEN_UNITS1 = 20
N_HIDDEN_UNITS2 = 5
N_OUTPUT =3

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_TIME_STEPS, N_INPUT], name="input")

lstm_layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN_UNITS1, forget_bias=1.0),tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN_UNITS2, forget_bias=1.0),tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_OUTPUT, forget_bias=1.0)]
lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layers)

outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_layers, input, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The input (**input** in the code) for the model should be in the shape of **[BATCH_SIZE, N_TIME_STEPS, N_INPUT]** and the output (outputs in the code)  of the RNN is in the shape of **[BATCH_SIZE, N_TIME_STEPS, N_OUTPUT]**

Hope this helps.

Comment: ah so the num_units input is simply the number of cells in that specific layer?

Comment: the first input parameter of BasicLSTMCell is called num_units (looking at the tensorflow document). So in your example it is called N_HIDDEN_UNITS1 for the first hidden layer and N_HIDDEN_UNITS2 for the second hidden layer

Comment: and from you example I take it that is just the number of cells in the hidden layer, which makes sense to me so thanks unless I'm wrong

Comment: No, actually in LSTM we called the hidden layer as an LSTM cell. Therefore, hidden layer in traditional RNN is replaced by the LSTM cell, In an LSTM cell, there can be a number of hidden units which is specified by num_units.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks very much! So I have two hidden LTSM cells, one with 20 hidden units and the other with 5 hidden units

Comment: Actually, I added 3 LSTM cells since u need an output of shape 3 x 1

Comment: oh right so the output vector is also a LTSM cell, I thought it would just be the result from the 2nd LSTM cell?